# Will Bitcoin and Ethereum be linked/bridged?

Tags: ether, bitcoin

Will Bitcoin be linked to Ethereum in the future? 
If so - how will it link, and when is this planned to happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the near future, it will be possible to verify transactions made in Bitcoin, in Ethereum, using BTC Relay (http://btcrelay.org/, https://medium.com/@ConsenSys/taking-stock-bitcoin-and-ethereum-4382f0a2f17#.v4ghgl4uk).

Thus, at the very least one would be able to build a decentralized exchange between Bitcoin & Ether. Using this transaction verification scheme, it will also be possible to build a federated multi-sig scheme in Bitcoin, that allows the creation of Bitcoin-as-a-token on Ethereum. Once you don't want to use that token anymore, you can use this federated multi-sig scheme to release the Bitcoin again on that side.

If Bitcoin implements the possibility to verify SPV proofs, then it would become possible to implement fully trust-less transfer of Bitcoin over to Ethereum.